# How to create a smartpointer to a class and initialize the class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have

```
p2t::CDT* cdt = new CDT(p2d);
```

where p2d is an object that is passed by reference to the CDT class constructor.

I want to replace this with a smartpointer:

```
std::unique_ptr< p2t::CDT> cdt(p2d);
```

but it doesn't work in the way I wrote.

- What is the correct way of writing the smart pointer for it?
- After creating the smart pointer, do I use the pointer like a normal pointer (ie. (*cdt) gives me the object it points to, right? ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use

```
std::unique_ptr<p2t::CDT> cdt(new p2t::CDT());
```

there is some documentation about it.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

About your question:

> After creating the smart pointer, do I use the pointer like a normal pointer (ie. (*cdt) gives me the object it points to, right? ) ?

Yes, `*cdt` gives you object that it points too, because smart pointers overloads `*` operator.
And no, you cant use it like regular pointer, its a template class instance, so giving it to function like `void foo(p2t::CDT * ptr);` wont work.

BUT! there is a member function `get()` that will return normal pointer, which is wrapped into `unique_ptr` object that you can use with a such function.

```
void bar(Foo * ptr)
{
    // some operations with ptr
}

std::unique_ptr<Foo> cdt(new Foo());
bar(cdt.get()); // can do so
```

Also, smart pointers overloads `->` operator, so you can call methods of some class just like with regular pointer.

```
class Foo{
public:
   void bar();
};

std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo());
ptr->bar(); // it works!
```

Comment: +1. You could also mention `std::make_unique` available in C++14.